# How I can transform the variables 'population_in_millions ' using the log, to the base 7, transformation

Tags: r

I'm trying with below code but something is missing is any one know whats wrong??

```
# Loading the datasets and define some variables
    library(dslabs)
    data(murders)

    population_in_millions <- murders$population/7^10
    total_m <- murders$total

    plot(population_in_millions, total_m)
```

Comment: I can not reach the `countryA` data? Which version of the package are you using?

Comment: updated please check

Comment: Wouldn't you want to divide by 10^7 instead of 7^10?

Comment: Why do you want to do log? Your question isn't clear to me but if you're just trying to get population in millions you divided by the wrong value which is maybe all that is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form `log(x, base)` computes logarithms with base `base` (see [this](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Log.html)). 
Try

```
population_in_millions <- log(murders$population, base = 7)
plot(population_in_millions, total_m)
```

Comment: Why would taking log base 7 give population in millions?